# Murach's Java Servlets 3rd edition NullPointerException when writing to database from application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm working with Murach's Java Servlets and JSP 3rd edition and have having difficulty with the ch12email project (which can be downloaded from murach.com). My issue is that when running the application and entering data into the form and submitting, I get the following HTTP Status 500 error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    murach.data.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:32)
    murach.data.UserDB.emailExists(UserDB.java:80)
    murach.email.EmailListServlet.doPost(EmailListServlet.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is where the error is occurring:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And that class's constructor:

```
private ConnectionPool() {
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/murach");
        //dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/murach");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

However, I'm able to connect to the database in Netbeans and view or edit data in the database. This is the Resource tag in the context.xml file for the database user and password information:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/murach" auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach" 
    username="root" password="67890"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
    logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

I'm not completely sure what information would be needed to thoroughly troubleshoot this problem, so please let me know whatever information would help and I'll be sure to supply it!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a resource ref defined in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/murach</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution, but was able to install it on a Windows 7 VM successfully following the steps in the book as normal. Afterwards I moved all of my files to an external and reinstalled Windows 10 on my laptop (the machine that was having the issue). After that I followed the book's instructions again and it worked. Thank you for anyone that took the time to try to help!